# can I combine foreign key with primary key in `id` column in 1 table?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, primary-key

Here is the sample

```
CREATE TABLE apple(
 `appleId` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `apple_Name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`appleId`)
); 

ALTER TABLE fruit(
 `fruitID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREAMENT = 1505,
 `fruitgroupname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `quantityfruit` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
 `appleIDFK` int(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`fruitID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `apple` (`appleId`),
 CONSTRAINT apple_IDFK FOREIGN KEY (`appleIDFK`) REFERENCES apple(`appleId`)   
);
```

This is the output that what I want

```
fruitID     fruitgroupname   apple_name   quantityfruit
---------   --------------   ----------   -------------
1505-A001   Fruit Tree       Apple        100
```

I want to save `fruitID` like 1505-A001 (combining 2 Primary key in 1 column on HTML view)in fruit output. So, when I call it said like that. Combining 2 data on that output separate with `-` between `fruitID` and `appleID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, and your SQL statements don't work, but assuming you mean something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE apple(
    `appleId` int(10) NOT NULL,  
    `apple_Name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,   
    PRIMARY KEY (`appleId`) 
);

CREATE TABLE fruit(  
    `fruitID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    `fruitgroupname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,  
    `quantityfruit` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,  
    `appleIDFK` int(10) NOT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY (`fruitID`),  
    CONSTRAINT apple_IDFK FOREIGN KEY (`appleIDFK`) REFERENCES apple(`appleId`)    
);
```

And data such as:

```
INSERT INTO apple (appleId, apple_Name) VALUES (1, 'Apple');
INSERT INTO fruit (fruitID, fruitGroupName, quantityfruit, appleIDFK) VALUES (1505, 'Fruit Tree', 100, 1);
```

Then you can get the sort of output you indicated with:

```
SELECT f.fruitID, f.fruitgroupname, a.apple_name, f.quantityfruit  
FROM fruit f 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN apple a ON f.appleIDFK = a.appleId;
```

Or, to get exactly the same output:

```
SELECT CONCAT(f.fruitID, '-A', LPAD(f.appleIDFK, 3, '0')) "fruitID",
   f.fruitgroupname, a.apple_name, f.quantityfruit
   FROM fruit f
      LEFT OUTER JOIN apple a ON f.appleIDFK = a.appleId;
```

Note that instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN` you can use `INNER JOIN` which executes faster, but then you won't see any `fruit` records that aren't `apple`s.

Comment: using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will combining 2 primary key in 1 column?, im using `INNER JOIN` but idk how to combining 2 primary key in 1 column. so, `CONCAT` is the one who can combining 2 value in 1 place?

Comment: @Ainal Yaqin `LEFT OUTER JOIN ON` a primary key in two tables will combine each record from the first table with a record from the second table if one exists. (If not, it will just use the record from the first table without combining.) `INNER JOIN ON` the same primary key will do the same, except it will only give you the records where the value for the primary key in the first table also exists in the second table. `CONCAT` is just for displaying purposes - yes, it can combine two (or more) columns into one column in the result set.